# How to sort a TJSONArray in delphi

Tags: json, delphi

I have a TJSONArray filled with TJSONObjects in delphi. Is there a method that will sort the json array given a key that all the json objects share?

Comment: There is no such method, you will have to sort the objects manually. And to make matters worse, `TJSONArray` does not allow you to alter individual elements at all. So you would have to extract the objects into your own list/array, sort it as needed, and then create a new `TJSONArray`, or at least use the `TJSONArray.SetElements()` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this problem a while back. I didn't find any methods that could do the sorting so ended up building my own:

```
procedure SortJsonArray(aJsonArray: TJsonArray)
var
  cntr: Integer;
  elementList: TList<TJSONValue>;
begin
  // Sort the elements. We have to sort them because they change constantly
  elementList := TList<TJSONValue>.Create;
  try
    // Get the elements
    for cntr := 0 to aJsonArray.Count - 1 do
      elementList.Add(aJsonArray.Items[cntr]);
    elementList.Sort(TComparer<TJSONValue>.Construct(
        function(const Left, Right: TJSONValue): Integer
        var
          leftObject: TJSONObject;
          rightObject: TJSONObject;
        begin            
          // You should do some error checking here and not just cast blindly
          leftObject := TJSONObject(Left);
          rightObject := TJSONObject(Right);
          // Compare here. I am just comparing the ToStrings but you will probably
          // want to compare something else.
          Result := 
              TComparer<string>.Default.Compare(leftObject.ToString, rightObject.ToString);
        end));
    aJsonArray.SetElements(elementList);
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      // We only free the element list when there is an exception because SetElements 
      // takes ownership of the list.
      elementList.Free;
      raise;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

You need to make sure that you don't free the element list because SetElements takes over the list when you pass in the list.

Answer (score -1):

I used FDMemTable which allowed to sort by any field

Comment: Welcome! Please read [How To Answer Well](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)